# Find directories missing .csv file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have ~1000 directories, containing various `.csv` files within them. I am trying to check if a specific type of csv file, containing a filename that begins with `PTSD_OCOTBER`, exists in each directory.

If this file does not exist in the directory, I want to print out that directory into a .txt file.

Here is what I have so far.

```
import os,sys,time,shutil
import subprocess


#determine filetype to look for. 
file_type = ".csv"
print("Running file counter for" + repr(file_type))

#for each folder in the root directory
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        if("GeneSet" in subdir):
            folder_name = subdir.rsplit('/', 1)[-1] #get the folder name. 
        for f in files:
                #unclear how to write this part. 
                #how to tell if no files exist in directory?
```

This successfully finds the `.csv` files of interest, but how do achieve the above?

Comment: you already have the `folder_name` variable available, you can use a `with open("dirs.txt","w") as fileptr:` and use `fileptr.write(folder_name + "\n")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `files` is the list of files in that directory that you are currently walking. You want to know if there are no files that start with `PTSD_OCOTBER` (`PTSD_OCTOBER` ?):

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        if("GeneSet" in subdir):
            folder_name = subdir.rsplit('/', 1)[-1] #get the folder name. 
        dir_of_interest = not any(f.startswith('PTSD_OCOTBER') for f in files)
        if dir_of_interest:
            # do stuff with folder_name
```

Now you want to save the results into a text file? If you have a Unix-style computer, then you can use output redirection on your terminal, such as

```
python3 fileanalysis.py > result.txt
```

after writing `print(folder_name)` instead of `# do stuff with folder_name`.

Or you can use Python itself to write the file, such as:

```
found_dirs = []
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    ...
    if dir_of_interest:
        found_dirs.append(folder_name)

with open('result.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(found_dirs))
```